# struts2-jquery-plugin+struts2-json-plugin : is it possible to have many JSON getters methods in the same action class?

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2, jsonplugin

My question is : In case of using struts2-jquery-plugin+struts2-json-plugin, can I define many functions such as :

```
@Actions( {
        @Action(value = "/func1", results = {
          @Result(name = "str1", type = "json")
        })
      })
public String func1(){
  //instructions
  return "str1";
}

@Actions( {
        @Action(value = "/func2", results = {
          @Result(name = "str2", type = "json")
        })
      })
public String func2(){
  //instructions
  return "str2";
}
```

and many JSON methods getters such as :

```
public String getJSON1()
{
  func1();
}
public String getJSON2()
{
  return func2();
}
```

in the same action class?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the goal. How are the getJSONn functions intended to be related to the action methods?

Comment: I think he means the get json methods are the actions. Yes you can have multiple action methods which return json. This tends to come up with FindEmployees, FindCustomers, FindSuppliers where there are the same search parameters. However it makes more sense to move the commonality which makes for multiple actions into it's own setter with string or better enum then you are back to one action.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that in the past and it didn't work. But i devised a workaround, maybe that will be useful to you. The workaround passes a parameter to the action. e.g.

Action Class

```
private String jsonMethod;
//getters and setters

public String getJSON()
{
     if(jsonMethod.equals("findEmp"))
     {

     }else if(jsonMethod.equals("findCust"))
     {

     }
     return SUCCESS;
}
```

from your jsp

```
<s:url id="findEmp" namespace="/" action="getJSON" >
    <s:param name="jsonMethod">findEmp</s:param>
</s:url> 
<s:url id="findCust" namespace="/" action="getJSON" >
    <s:param name="jsonMethod">findCust</s:param>
</s:url>
```